# Power BI May 2021 Launch Error: AS Process PID = 16228 has exited with ExitCode=-1073741792, ExitTime=____

Tags: visual-studio, dll, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

The Power BI May 2021 version throwing an error since July 1st and I am not able to open it.

The first error is of "msmdrsv.exe - Bad Image" which says *C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop_14.0.30035.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\VCRUNTIME140.dll is wither not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support. Error status 0xc0000020.*

Upon clicking OK in the dialog box, another similar error appears for VCP140.dll file.

In the background, it says *Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)*

Upon clicking OK in the bad image dialog box a couple of times, the last error occurs is *AS Process PID=7456 has exited with ExitCode=-1073741792,ExitTime=[TIME STAMP]*

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFvG9.jpg)

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R42sl.jpg)

Tried many things including

1. Restarting the system
2. Uninstalling and reinstalling the Power BI Desktop from Microsoft Store
3. Uninstalling and reinstalling Visual C++ Redistirbutable Visual Studio 2015 as suggested in some other posts

However, nothing has worked so far.

Looking for more suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this for Power Bi service or On Premise Power Bi Report Server? The Desktop versions are different.......

Comment: This is Power BI Desktop version of May 2021. I installed it from Microsoft Store.

Comment: If it's Version: 2.93.1681.0 (May 2021), Released: July 6, 2021 then it is for Power Bi Reporting Services On Premise only and is working fine for us.